# Import em Python

Tags: python-3.x, importação

Como eu faço import em Python sendo esta classe criada por mim?

Exemplo: em java eu crio uma classe de conexão e posso fazer o importe dela na classe de estoque para poder fazer a persistência no banco, mas não sei fazer isto em Python e vejo exemplos na internet mas de módulos, ainda não vi de classes.

Answer (score 3):

Caso o arquivo que contem a classe esteja no mesmo diretório do arquivo que vai importar basta apenas:

```
from nome_do_arquivo import Nome_da_classe_nesse_arquivo
```

Exemplo temos 2 arquivos no mesmo lugar chamado **minhaClasse.py** e o outro **main.py**

Em **minhaClasse.py** teríamos o seguinte código:

```
class ClasseQueNaoFazNada():
    def nada():
        print("Nada")
```

E no arquivo **main.py** vamos chamar a classe criada e executar o seu método usando esse código:

```
from minhaClasse import ClasseQueNaoFazNada

ClasseQueNaoFazNada.nada()
```

Assim podemos importar e usar uma classe criada por nos mesmos.