# Trazendo arquivos, classes e métodos de outro arquivo Python

Tags: python-3.x, classes

Preciso trazer um arquivo de classes como esse que se encontra em classe.py:

```
class Despesas(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Prioridade = Prioridade()
        self.Situacao = True
        self.Valor = 0.0
        self.Categoria = ''
```

Para o arquivo View.py.

No PHP eu consigo fazer essa função com o método require('Nome_arquivo'),
Como fazer isso em Python 3.6?

Comment: Algo como `from classe import Despesas`

Comment: Pergunta básica demais sobre a sintaxe da linguagem

Comment: https://wiki.python.org.br/ModulosPacotes   -sugiro dar uma lida, mesmo que por cima, no tutorial - tem uma tradução bem legal:
https://wiki.python.org.br/Tutorial_Python

Comment: Eu coloquei como fora de escopo no voto de fechar, mas também é uma duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231365/import-em-python

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Import em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231365/import-em-python)

Answer (score -2):

Se percebi bem a sua pergunta, tem de ter os 2 ficheiros na mesma diretoria e basta fazer:

```
import classe
despesas = classe.Despesas(objeto)
#ou 
from classe import Despesas
despesas = Despesas(objeto)
```